# Is it off-topic asking who were "famous" mathematicians / logicians?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I want to know who you consider the most famous / important mathematicians and logicians. Would that be off-topic? I know of Gödel, A.Church, Turing, Emil Post, Saul Kripke and I wonder if these are the 5 most famous modern / symbolic logicians or more a coincidence that it's been their theses I've studied?

Comment: I agree with Qiaochu that asking for "most famous" is inherently subjective hence not a great question for math.se.  Also it is not quite clear what "modern / symbolic logicians" means: there are relatively few living symbolic logicians.  (Of your list, only Kripke is living; most of the others did their prominent work in the first half of the 20th century.)  Contemporary "mathematical logic" is mostly uninterested in foundational issues.  It is a broad field, but (arguably!) its greatest living practitioners are **Ehud Hrushovski** and **Saharon Shelah**.

Comment: is 5 a fixed number? Asking just for names of famous mathematicians / logicians in the XX and XXI century (maybe explaining why) would be a soft question, and would have more chances to be accepted.

Comment: What about Robinson, Kleene, Tarski, Quine, Henkin, Zilber, Malitz, Magidor, A. Levy, Los, Feferman, and so many others?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark The information might be hard to obtain, but I don't see why this is *inherently* subjective. If the question would be who is the most famous person in congress, we could rely on polling information and get an objective answer.

Comment: @Michael: In fact I suspect that if you asked representatives of the Democratic and Republican parties your question about famous congressmen, they'd find plenty to argue about, especially the precise interpretation of "most famous".  I suppose you can make almost any question objective by arbitrarily choosing precise definitions, but then it becomes less useful to a broad audience ("too localized").  Moreover, a question whose answer is obtained by taking a poll is not a mathematics question, it seems to me, hence probably off-topic for this site.

Comment: OK I won't say that Fermat was famous.....

Comment: I do not understand why this question has a close vote for being "not constructive". It is very constructive! Now, if the question the OP is asking about was, indeed, asked then it should be closed as "not constructive", but this question should not be!

Comment: I think questions of this kind are in poor taste, even if that was not your intention. Unless an exhaustive list is presented, any attempt to answer this question would end up offending somebody because they were excluded, or their work was misrepresented, or somebody else was excluded or misrepresented, or an area was not given enough presence, or... Plus, it would set up a bad precedent, since it makes it seem as if mathematics itself is secondary (a means to a sort of fame, if you wish).

Comment: More interesting, and useful, is to ask for current trends of research, or texts were you can learn about current developments, or about the background material needed to understand these developments. Any reasonable source would end up providing you with the names of the researchers involved in those results.

Answer (score 11):

I don't like it (it's subjective / argumentative). What are you actually planning on doing with this information?

Comment: I plan to do a filling of my knowledge gap e.g. I'm aware of famous results such as incompleteness theorem, Chruch's thesis, Kripke semantics but I don't know the details of the results in logic, I only owned one logic book (Graeme Forbes) which didn't tell the details and mostly just the basics. Math is such a large subject so I'm looking at logic and trying to understand how large the subject logic is since it seems much smaller than math. I'm also interested in history and how science and mathematics progressed last century (Aristotle is too far back).

Comment: @Nick: then ask about that instead ("what are some references that will help me understand the landscape of logic?" or something like that).

Comment: @NickRosencrantz: On his blog [logicmatters.net](http://www.logicmatters.net/) math.SE user [Peter Smith](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/35151/peter-smith) has a study guide [Teach yourself logic](http://www.logicmatters.net/students/tyl/) that gives sound advice on where to start. It is written for students of philosophy, but should equally well be applicable for mathematicians.